# how to debug https post issue works with REST client not with lambda

Tags: rest, post, aws-lambda

I am making a POST call from amazon lambda function as below

```
    var noteBody = 
                            {
                              ...
    };

 var options = {
      appid: "amzn1.echo-sdk-ams.app.your-app-id",
      host: hostName,
      path: aptmtPath,
      method: "POST",
      json: true,
      'gzip': true,
      headers: {
                        Authorization: 'Basic ' + auth,
                        'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.oracle.adf.resourceitem+json'

                    },
      body: noteBody
    };  


         https.get(options, function(res) {
            console.log("note creation response received with response code:" + res.statusCode);
```

The response code gets printed 201. Which means successful post. However, I dont see any data posted.

The same thing when i try using a chrome extension called REST client it works fine. here is what raw request looks like (which works)

```
Authorization: Basic XXXX
Content-Type: application/vnd.oracle.adf.resourceitem+json
Cookie: JSESSIONID=_y1lmLqOsH-SQ5EhMTOghRW0W2ThiQwehDk0QAc6hWl5dqLTxjw1!492604637; ORA_FND_SESSION_FUSIONDB=DEFAULT_PILLAR:3tzuXU7XnpS8szvj4S0U4Lauq0eiS4E40GSWytkui3yGUy75ABCWWIErvUozaYHR:1470447149500; ORA_FUSION_PREFS=v1.0~bG9jYWxlPWVufmRlZmF1bHRMYW5ndWFnZU1hcmtlcj10cnVl
Content-Length: 108
```

## Source message

```
POST /salesApi/resources/11.1.11/activities/308673/child/Note HTTP/1.1
 HOST: XXXX
 authorization: Basic XXX
 content-type: application/vnd.oracle.adf.resourceitem+json
 cookie: JSESSIONID=_y1lmLqOsH-SQ5EhMTOghRW0W2ThiQwehDk0QAc6hWl5dqLTxjw1!492604637; ORA_FND_SESSION_FUSIONDB=DEFAULT_PILLAR:3tzuXU7XnpS8szvj4S0U4Lauq0eiS4E40GSWytkui3yGUy75ABCWWIErvUozaYHR:1470447149500; ORA_FUSION_PREFS=v1.0~bG9jYWxlPWVufmRlZmF1bHRMYW5ndWFnZU1hcmtlcj10cnVl
 content-length: 108

 {
 "NoteTxt" : "dGVzdCBub3RlIGZyb20gY2hyb21l",
 "NoteTypeCode" : "GENERAL",
 "VisibilityCode": "INTERNAL"
 }
```

How do I debug it?

Comment: Instead of trying to test a similar REST call in Chrome, why don't you trying running the actual NodeJS code locally? You should be able to test and debug this code locally before deploying to Lambda.